# Access violation 0xc00005 in C

Tags: c, access-violation

I have been writing a program that accepts student information through an array of structure and then performs various operations on it.

Whenever I try to perform any of the two operations i.e 1 and 2, I get an access violation.

Here is the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void linear();
void bubble();
void binary();
void insertion();

int i, j, temp;

struct kaksha{
    int RegNo;
    char Name[50];
    char Branch[50];
    float GradePoint;
};

int main()
{
    int size, choice;
    struct kaksha *ptr;

    ptr = (struct kaksha *)malloc(sizeof(struct kaksha)); //Allocate memory to the structure.
    struct kaksha jwak[50];
    printf("Enter the number of students.\n");
    scanf("%d", &size);
    printf("Enter the respective details.\n");
    printf("          \n");
    for (i = 1 ; i < size + 1; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter registration number for student number %d.\n", i);
        scanf("%d", &jwak[i].RegNo);
        printf("Enter CGPA for student number %d.\n", i);
        scanf("%f", &jwak[i].GradePoint);
        printf("Enter name for student number %d.\n", i);
        scanf("%s", &jwak[i].Name);
        //gets(jwak[i].Name);
        printf("Enter branch of student number %d.\n", i);
        scanf("%s", &jwak[i].Branch);
        //gets(jwak[i].Branch);
    }
    printf("Select the operation to be formed.\n");
    printf("1. Call linear search function to display data of student with a particular registration number.\n");
    printf("2. Call bubble sort function to arrange data of students according to registration number.\n");
    printf("3. Apply binary search on the output of option 2 to display data of a student with a particular registration number.\n");
    printf("4. Use and modify Insertion sort logic to arrange data of students in descending order of CGPA.\n");
    scanf("%d",choice);

    switch(choice)
    {
    case 1:
        linear(jwak,size);
    case 2:
        bubble(jwak,size);
    case 3:
        binary(jwak,size);
    case 4:
        insertion(jwak,size);
    }
}

void linear(struct kaksha jwak[],int size)
{
    int query;
    printf("Enter the register number of the student you wish to query.\n");
    scanf("%d", &query);
    for (i = 0 ; i < size ; i++)
    {
        if (jwak[i].RegNo == query)
        {
            printf("Name of the student is %s.\n",jwak[i].Name);
            printf("Branch of the student is %d.\n",jwak[i].Branch);
            printf("Grade point of the student is %f.\n",jwak[i].GradePoint);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Corresponding entry does not exist.\n");
        }
    }
}

void bubble(struct kaksha jwak[],int size)
{
    for (i = 0 ; i < size ; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0 ; j < (size - i - 1) ; j++)
        {
            if (jwak[j].RegNo > jwak[j + 1].RegNo)
            {
                temp = jwak[j].RegNo;
                jwak[j].RegNo = jwak[j + 1].RegNo;
                jwak[j + 1].RegNo = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("Data arranged according to increasing order of registration        number.\n");
    for (i = 0 ; i < size ; i++)
    {
        printf("Registration number of the student is %d.\n", jwak[i].RegNo);
        printf("Name of the student is %s.\n", jwak[i].Name);
        printf("Branch of the student is %d.\n", jwak[i].Branch);
        printf("Grade point of the student is %f.\n", jwak[i].GradePoint);
    }
}
```

Comment: make your code readable so it's easier to tell what the problem is. Use a debugger to find out where the problem occurs.

Comment: Don't cast the return of malloc in C.  Also, include <stdlib> so that the proper prototype is present for malloc.

Comment: Please don't just repost your question when you didn't get an answer the first time.

Comment: what this `ptr = (struct kaksha *)malloc(sizeof(struct kaksha));` is good for?

Comment: @milevyo I thought I would need it to pass the structure via address function(&ptr). But the need didnt arise.

Comment: basically you should not use `struct kaksha jwak[50];` but instead and according to `printf("Enter the number of students.\n");` you should allocate memory `ptr =malloc(size * sizeof(struct kaksha));` then use ptr instead of jwak ( use ptr, not &ptr);

Comment: On which line does the access violation occur??  Try compiling with debug symbols and running it under GDB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[David](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2191105/david-hoelzer) has already pointed out the [problem with strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35253741/access-violation-0xc00005-in-c/35254699#35253770). The second problem is here:

```
scanf("%d",choice);
```

You forgot the `&`:

```
scanf("%d", &choice);
```

**Tip:** if you used a debugger, you would have immediately found the line and I'm sure you would have discovered the typo yourself.

Comment: Yes I did use the debugger and found the source. Thanks anyway good sir.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `scanf` for a string, you do *not* pass the address.

```
scanf("%s",&jwak[i].Name);
```

You do this several times.  You do need to do this for integers, floats, etc., but remember that in C you are using a byte array that is *already* (effectively) a pointer.  So:

```
scanf("%s",jwak[i].Name);
```

This is almost certainly the source of the access violations.

Also, as I've mentioned in the comments, when using `malloc` in C, do not cast the return value.  Additionally, include `<stdlib.h>` so that you have the proper prototype for `malloc`.

Comment: Removed the ampersands, still having the access violations.

Answer (score -1):

I see several importatnt issues

1. You never check whether `size` is less than `50` which is the size of your array.
2. You start the loop at `i == 1` and end it at `i < size + 1`. In [c](/questions/tagged/c) arrays are indexed from `0` to `size - 1` so it should be

   ```
   for (int i = 0 ; i < size ; ++i)
   ```
3. When calling `scanf()` with the `"%s"` specifier you should not pass the address of the array, the array is automatically converted to a pointer to it's first element the address of `&array` and `array` is the same, but `&array + 1` and `array + 1` will not be the same. ([Read this answer for more of this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35253770/1983495))
4. In your `switch` statement there is no break, so all the cases fall through and that means that if the user choose `1` for example, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4` ... and so on will be executed.
5. As mentioned [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35253770/1983495) by not including *stdlib.h* the prototype of `malloc()` is wrong which would lead to undefined behavior. The compiler should be telling you "*warning: implicit declaration of builtin function `malloc()`* you might be ignoring that but you shouldn't.
6. You always ignore the return value of `scanf()` and that could also lead to undefined behavior.

Comment: I did this deliberately so that the student number in printf starts from 1 and not 0.

Comment: But that's wrong, you are using `i` as an index and in your code you are potentially accessing one element after the last, just add 1 to the student number, didn't that occur to you? Also, after fixing your code style I found more problems.

Comment: Absolutely right about 5. I did ignore cz I was unable to figure out the problem. Thanks again. Can not including stdlib be the cause of access violation?

Comment: Yes it can be, but I would use a debugger to be sure. Also, on Linux there is a tool called [valgrind](http://www.valgrind.org) that is extremely useful when you need to debug a memory access problem. I don't know on MS Windows of any tool like that. Valgrind also works on mac. And finally, I don't think you need `malloc()` in this situation or at least not the way you are using it.

Comment: Commented out the malloc() usage. Still stuck on the access violation though.